# spring boot thymleaf resources are not working for all pages

Tags: java, jquery, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am new to theymleaf template engine. I have a spring boot web application which uses theymleaf template engine. Below is my project structure.

[image]

I have `home.html` in which I have called header(in `header.html`) and footer(in `footer.html`) fragments and for the content part I am calling another fragment which is familytree(which is in `familytree.html`) and every thing works fine until now. I am getting the expected view when I run the spring boot application.

Issue: Now I have created another html page called `viewfulltree.html`( copied the `home.html` page and pasted in the same directory and renamed it as `viewfulltree.html` to make sure every thing works just like same as `home.html` works). this `viewfulltree.html` is just another copy of `home.html` with different name. now, when I am returning to this `viewfulltree.html` page from my controller class it is not able to find the `css,js,images` files as a result the view is messed up with no style, no action , no images. I am not sure what is the mistake I have done in my configuration. Since both are in the same directory and using the same `header.html` fragment so I am expecting that both should be able access the static contents in the same way.

controller class::

```
@Controller
public class DefaultController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String defaultHome(){
        return "redirect:home";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/home", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String home(Model model){
        List<TreeNode> nodesList = null;
        nodesList = getNodes();
        ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            List<String> menuItems = new ArrayList<>();
            List<FamilyTree> treesList = familyTreeService.findAll();
            treesList.forEach( tree ->{
                menuItems.add(tree.getFamilyTreeName());
            });
            if(!menuItems.isEmpty()){
                model.addAttribute("menuItems", menuItems);
            }

            model.addAttribute("ft_items", 
jsonMapper.writeValueAsString(nodesList));
            model.addAttribute("profile", new Profile());
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            log.warn(e.getMessage());
        }
        return "/home";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/viewfulltree/{familyTreeId}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String getTree(@PathVariable("familyTreeId") String familyTreeId, Model model){
        List<TreeNode> nodesList = null;
        nodesList = getTreeNodes(Long.valueOf(familyTreeId));
        ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            List<String> menuItems = new ArrayList<>();
            List<FamilyTree> treesList = familyTreeService.findAll();
            treesList.forEach( tree ->{
                menuItems.add(tree.getFamilyTreeName());
            });
            if(!menuItems.isEmpty()){
                model.addAttribute("menuItems", menuItems);
            }

            model.addAttribute("ft_items", jsonMapper.writeValueAsString(nodesList));
            model.addAttribute("profile", new Profile());
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            log.warn(e.getMessage());
        }
        return "/viewfulltree";
    }
}
```

Note: the only difference I found between these two files while running the application is the url. I go to home.html source from browser and click on any css file it gave the below url and the css file found.

```
found:http://localhost:7030/familytree/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

but when i view the viewfulltree.html source from browser and click on any css file it gave me the below url and the css file not found, gave 404 error.

```
not-found(404):http://localhost:7030/familytree/viewfulltree/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

I am not able to figure it out where do I need to change the code. Let me know If am need to give any part of the code.

home.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<title>Family-tree</title>
    <div th:replace="header :: header-css" ></div>
    <div th:replace="familytree :: family-tree-css" ></div>
</head>
<body>
    <div th:replace="header :: header" ></div>
    <section layout:fragment="custom-content">
        <div th:replace="familytree :: family-tree" ></div>
    </section>

</body>
</html>
```

header.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <div th:fragment="header-css">
            <!-- this is header css -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css}" />

        <style>
        h1{
            color:#0000FF;
        }

        h2{
            color:#FF0000;
        }

        footer{
            margin-top:60px;
        }
        </style>
    </div>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div th:fragment="header">
        <!-- this is header -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" id="ft_menuItem">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand active" th:href="@{/home}">Family Tree</a>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Trees
                            <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li th:unless="${#lists.isEmpty(menuItems)}" th:each="menuItem : ${menuItems}">
                                    <a th:href="@{/viewfulltree/2}" th:text="${menuItem}">Create new Tree</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a th:href="@{/createtreeform}">Create new Tree</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a th:href="@{/events}">Event Calendar</a></li>
                        <li><a th:href="@{/aboutus}">About Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <script th:src="@{webjars/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js}"></script>
        <script th:src="@{webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

familytree.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <title>Family-tree</title>
        <div th:fragment="family-tree-css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" th:href='@{css/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.css}'/>
        <link th:href='@{css/primitives.latest.css?3710}' media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <style type="text/css">

    .table-user-information > tbody > tr {
        border-top: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);
    }

    .table-user-information > tbody > tr:first-child {
        border-top: 0;
    }


    .table-user-information > tbody > tr > td {
        border-top: 0;
        font-size: 13px;
    }
    .toppad
    {
        margin-top:20px;
    }
        </style>
        </div>

    </head>
    <body>
    <div th:fragment="family-tree">
    <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8 nopadding">
                    <div id="btn50">50%</div>
                    <div id="btn80">80%</div>
                    <div id="btn100">100%</div>
                    <div id="btn130">130%</div>
                    <div id="orgdiagram"  style="height: 480px; overflow: hidden; border-style: dotted; border-width: 1px;"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 nopadding">
                    <div class="panel panel-info">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                          <h4 class="panel-title">full Name here</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                          <div class="row">
                                <div class=" col-md-12 col-lg-12 "> 
                                  <table class="table table-user-information">
                                    <tbody>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td><img alt="User Pic" src="images/male.png" class="img-circle img-responsive" width="50px"></img></td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td>Gender</td>
                                        <td>Female</td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td>Age</td>
                                        <td>30</td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td>Date of Birth:</td>
                                        <td>06/23/2013</td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td>Anniversary Date</td>
                                        <td>01/24/1988</td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td>Child Of</td>
                                        <td>Parent Name goes here</td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td>Marital status</td>
                                        <td>Married</td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td>No. of Children</td>
                                        <td>4</td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td>Phone Number</td>
                                        <td>
                                            123-4567-890(Landline)<br></br>
                                            555-4567-890(Mobile)
                                        </td>
                                      </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                  </table>
                                </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-footer">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="create-Profile-form" title="Create new user">
            <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>


            <form id="add-profile" th:object="${profile}">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="hidden" id="in_parentId" th:field="*{parentId}"></input>
                        </td> 
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Full Name
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="in_profileName" th:field="*{profileName}"/>
                        </td> 
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            First Name
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <input type="text" id="in_firstName" th:field="*{firstName}"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Last Name
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="in_lastName" th:field="*{lastName}"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Gender
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select id="in_gender" th:field="*{gender}" >
                                <option th:value="male" th:text="Male">Male</option>
                                <option th:value="female" th:text="Fe-Male">Fe-Male</option>            
                            </select>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>    
            </form>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" th:src='@{js/bootstrap.min.js}'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" th:src='@{js/jquery-1.9.1.js}'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" th:src='@{js/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js}'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" th:src='@{js/primitives.min.js?3710}'></script>
        <script th:inline="javascript">
        /*<![CDATA[*/
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        var dialog, form;
        var treeNodes = [[${ft_items}]];

        var options = new primitives.orgdiagram.Config();
        var items = [];
        var buttons = [];

        $('form').on('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        });
        dialog = $("#create-Profile-form").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 400,
            width: 350,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Create an Profile": function(){

                    var profileData = {};
                    profileData.profileName = $("#in_profileName").val();
                    profileData.firstName = $("#in_firstName").val();
                    profileData.lastName = $("#in_lastName").val();
                    profileData.gender = $("#in_gender").val(),
                    profileData.parentId = $("#in_parentId").val();

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "profile/save",
                        async: true,
                        headers: {
                            'Accept': 'application/json',
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                        },
                        data: JSON.stringify(profileData),
                        success: function(result){
                            console.log(result);
                            dialog.dialog("close");
                            items = treeNodesToItems(JSON.stringify(result.object));
                            updateTreeWithItems(items);
                            $("#add-profile").trigger("reset");
                        },
                        error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
                            console.log(textStatus);
                             alert('error:' +textStatus + '\n:' +errorThrown);
                        }
                    });
                    dialog.dialog( "close" );
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                  dialog.dialog( "close" );
                }
              },
              close: function() {
                //form[ 0 ].reset();
                //allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
                $("#add-profile").trigger("reset");
              }
        });

        dialog.dialog("close");

        buttons.push(new primitives.orgdiagram.ButtonConfig("add", "ui-icon-person", "Add"));
        buttons.push(new primitives.orgdiagram.ButtonConfig("delete", "ui-icon-close", "Delete"));

        items = treeNodesToItems(treeNodes);

        options.pageFitMode = primitives.common.PageFitMode.None;
        options.items = items;
        options.buttons = buttons;          
        options.cursorItem = 0;
        options.hasSelectorCheckbox = primitives.common.Enabled.False;
        options.onButtonClick = function (e, data) {
            switch (data.name) {
                case "delete": 
                        if(data.context.parent==null || data.context.parent==''){
                            alert('you can not delete the parent node')
                        }
                        else{
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "DELETE",
                                url: "profile/delete/"+data.context.id,
                                //dataType: "json",
                                headers: {
                                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                                } ,
                                success: function(result){
                                    items = treeNodesToItems(JSON.stringify(result.object));
                                    updateTreeWithItems(items);
                                    console.log(result);
                                },
                                error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
                                    console.log(textStatus);
                                    alert('error:' +textStatus + '\n:' +errorThrown);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    break;
                case "add": 
                    /* get items collection */
                    //var items = jQuery("#orgdiagram").orgDiagram("option", "items");
                    /* create new item */
                    $('#in_parentId').val(data.context.id);
                    dialog.dialog( "open" );
                    break;
            }
        };
        jQuery("#orgdiagram").orgDiagram(options);

        $("#btn50").button().click(function () { onScale(0.5); });
        $("#btn80").button().click(function () { onScale(.8); });
        $("#btn100").button().click(function () { onScale(1); });
        $("#btn130").button().click(function () { onScale(1.3); });
    });

    function treeNodesToItems(treeNodes){
        var itemsToIterate = JSON.parse(treeNodes);
        var new_items = [];
        for(var i=0; i<itemsToIterate.length; i++){
            new_items.push(
                    new primitives.orgdiagram.ItemConfig({
                        id: itemsToIterate[i].id,
                        parent: itemsToIterate[i].parent,
                        title: itemsToIterate[i].title,
                        description: itemsToIterate[i].description,
                        image: "images/"+itemsToIterate[i].gender+".png"
                    }));
        }
        return new_items;
    }

    function updateTreeWithItems(ft_items){
        jQuery("#orgdiagram").orgDiagram({
            items: ft_items
        });
        jQuery("#orgdiagram").orgDiagram("update", /*Refresh: use fast refresh to update chart*/ primitives.orgdiagram.UpdateMode.Refresh);
    }


    function onScale(scale) {
        if (scale != null) {
            jQuery("#orgdiagram").orgDiagram({ scale: scale });
        }
        jQuery("#orgdiagram").orgDiagram("update", primitives.orgdiagram.UpdateMode.Refresh);
    }

         /*]]>*/
        </script>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: please also post your `header` and `familtytree` files.

Comment: as you have requested I have added header.html and familytree.html

Comment: you are genius...now it works fine as expected but one more small issue to be fixed...I am not able to reach the "images" directory from JQuery in this familytree.html file...this is the part of the code...
image: "images/"+itemsToIterate[i].gender+".png"

Comment: Please post you other issue as a seperate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your `header-css` fragment and update your css link like so

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css}" />
```

Comment: <li th:unless="${#lists.isEmpty(menuItems)}" th:each="menuItem : ${menuItems}">
                                    <a th:href="@{/viewfulltree/2}" th:text="${menuItem}">Create new Tree</a>
                                </li>

I want to replace that "2"  value in anchor tag with "menuItem" value but it is not working...any idea?

Comment: Try this `th:href="@{'/viewfulltree/' + ${menuItems.value}}"`